# Ordering Nav list items when using float right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I have the follwoing bootstrap navigation and it is styled how i want it except the list items are in the wrong order.

[image]

Tandems is the first list item and Contact is the last and I would like it to appear in the following order but float to the right. Eight and nine should be floated right.

[image]

Edit* Fiddle not working with pull right 
[image]

My html is as follows

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle are grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll col-md-2">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" /></a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right col-md-9">
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Tandems</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Charities <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="videobackground.html">NW Air Ambulance</a></li>
                            <li><a href="icons.html">Alder Hey Imagine</a></li>
                            <li><a href="typography.html">Clatterbridge</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pricingtables.html">We are Macmillan</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#pricing">Courses</a></li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#about">Prices</a></li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#blog">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Features <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="videobackground.html">Video Background</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="icons.html">Icons</a></li>
                            <li><a href="typography.html">Typography</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pricingtables.html">Pricing Tables</a></li>
                            <li><a href="buttons.html">Buttons</a></li>
                            <li><a href="progressbars.html">Progress Bars</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="blank.html">Blank Page</a></li>
                            <li><a href="404.html">404 Page</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">The Dropzone</a></li>
                    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Is there a way to do this using CSS? Here is a fiddle that includes my html and css.

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Please add the fiddle link.

Comment: You forgot to add the link to the Fiddle!

Comment: Oops sorry that would help https://jsfiddle.net/muncher39/Lh1udqa1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Flexbox** can do that..quite simply:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding:.25em;
  border:1px solid grey;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item 9</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Paulie_D, this is exactly what i need! works perfectly. I have never used flex before so i will need to do some reading on the subject to fully understand how this is being achieved. but using the the css you provided works for me, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Float the container element of the navigation list items to the right instead of the navigation items themselves.

Here is a simplified example.

```html
<header>
    <ul class="pull-right">
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

```css
header {
    overflow: hidden; /* clearfix */
    background-color: #222;
}
ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    color: #f1f1f1;
}
.pull-right {
    float: right;
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccvb2gqz/1)

When you float the navigation/list items themselves they get floated to the right in the order they appear in the markup which has the effect of reversing the order. *Tandems* appears first in the markup so it moves to the right **before** the next item, which is *Charities*. Now *Charities* moves to the right **before** the next item, *Courses*. This continues for all items as the line-up after the item that moved to the right before them giving the appearance of reversed order.

The fix, as mentioned, is to float the container of the items instead of the items themselves. This may require a clearfix on the parent container depending on the styling.

Comment: Hi, thats for your comment but i have tried your fiddle and it does not do what i want to achieve. Please add more nav items up to 9 and the second row does not float right. Please see the screen shot in my original post above